# Incorporating an arbitrary List of Boolean conditions into a Nest query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm looking for a good way to provide an arbitrary number of boolean conditions through the elastic NEST API by looping over a List of criteria and accumulating it -- one list item is one boolean condition -- for inclusion in a NEST Api Query call.

Following is an incomplete code sample of where I'm going with this, but am getting caught up in the fluent interface and how to best carry it out.

This example is based on a fictional Hotel document example made for illustration purposes.

```
Func<BoolQueryDescriptor<Hotel>, IBoolQuery> fnBool; // ... 

foreach (var someCriteriaObject in listOfCriteriaObjectsOneForEachBoolConditionIWantToAdd)
{
    // Idea is to build up fnBool or a similar construct for passing to the elastic query later on... 
    // Use .Must() for each item. 
}

// Finally execute the elastic Nest query with all the conditions included - 
ISearchResponse<Hotel> elasticResponse = this.Client.Search<Hotel>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(fnBool) // << pass the constructed boolean (all conditions)
    )
);
var results = elasticResponse.Hits; //... etc ...
```

Above is my first pseudo-code approach however I'm open to suggestions.

The actual elastic index would have a Hotel mapping like `http://localhost:9200/my-index/hotel/_mapping`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a query container:

```
List<QueryContainer> lst = new List<QueryContainer>();
```

Then add your queries:

```
lst.Add(Query<xxx>.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.zipCode).Value(zip)));
```

Finally, run the full query:

```
            ISearchResponse<xxx> results = elastic.Search<xxx>(s => s
                .Query(q => q
                    .ConstantScore(cs => cs
                        .Filter(ff => ff
                            .Bool(b => b.Must(lst.ToArray())))))
```

You can tweak for your needs, but thats the basic jyst. Note the last line with the ToArray() call, that's where you pass in the query container.

Comment: Thank you @SledgeHammer, this solution works very well; it's a lot simpler than the contortions I was heading toward with the elastic NEST API.